# How does Stack Overflow calculate the time?

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I have been logging into Stack Overflow daily. I'm at 33 consecutive days according to SO, but it should be more like 77. I am on the east coast of the US. One day, about 34 days ago, I checked some posts, looked at the questions and logged off.

When I went online the next day to check questions, it said 1 day consecutive, meaning that it didn't recognize my login the previous day.

How do I know when I log in whether a day has elapsed or not? I check like three times a day now just to make sure I get checked in for that day. It would be nice to just check the questions and be done.

P.S. I looked during my lunch, it was 12 noon here in Boston....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reply to your comment to Jeff: as a Bostonian, you're currently at UTC-5, meaning that your "day" on SO goes from 7 pm the previous day to 7 pm the day of. During the summer, you're at UTC-4; 8 pm the previous day to 8 pm the day of.

There's also a calendar for tracking your visit history. Open up [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155483/drewdin). Look for the line in your user info that says "visited x days, y consecutive" (see screenshot below). Click on it, and a calendar should pop up showing you whether you've visited for a given day, including the current day (see second screenshot below).

[image: user profile with link to visit calendar highlighted]
[image: user profile with calendar expanded out]

*Note: Only you can see the "visited," "openid," "email" and "real name" fields in your profile. This is just a mockup.*

Comment: PS: the profile didn't list consecutive days until June 22, 2010. We used to have to just guess. You kids these days don't know how good you have it....

Comment: @Popular Demand - That's exactly the answer I needed!

Comment: Wow, I never knew there was a calendar hiding in there...

Answer (score 2):

All days are measured in UTC. The day begins at 00:00:00 UTC and ends at 23:59:59 UTC.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, that still does not explain how i know if i get credit for logging in.

Comment: @Drewdin, that means if you login in the morning on Monday and late at night on Tuesday in your time zone, you could have had a complete day gap according to UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your activity didn't warrant enough to count as a visit?

It says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) (under enthusiast) that the exact amount of activity required for a visit isn't public information - perhaps your activity fell below this marker on that day.

Comment: You need to view more than the just the home page. I *think* any internal page (e.g. your profile page) would do.